# Why console can get the private field but console.log() cannot?

Tags: javascript, class, console, private, console.log

There is a class `Account` and its instance `acc1`, and I learned that '#' can be used to get private field, so I think the `#movements` property cannot be visited outside 'acc1', but I found that when I add a line of code  `console.log();`,it did return an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Private field '#movements' must be declared in an enclosing class;`, but when I input `acc1` in the console, I did see the exact value of that property, and when the code `console.log(acc1);`also show the acc1 instance that contains #movements, but would't the private property be hidden when log acc1, and wouldn't it return an error when I input acc1.#movements?
The whole code is following:

```
class Account {
  // 1) Public fields (instances)
  locale = navigator.language;

  // 2) Private fields (instances)
  #movements = [];
  #pin;

  constructor(owner, currency, pin) {
    this.owner = owner;
    this.currency = currency;
    this.#pin = pin;
  }
}

const acc1 = new Account('Jay', 'EUR', 1);
console.log(acc1);
// console.log(acc1.#movements);
```

I have searched this question in stackoverflow but did not get the answer, maybe it's because that's too fundamental?

Comment: The console can do whatever it wants. It's "all powerful", it's a browser-integrated tool to help you debug stuff. However, access to private fields through Javascript code must obey the rules of how private fields work, and you cannot access a private field from outside its class to pass it to `console.log`.